# Remove element from a Python list until found a specific character

Tags: python, list

Hello I have this Python List

```
carachter = "@"

list = ['Montpellier', 'Saint-Etienne', '@', 'Strasbourg', 'Reims', '@', 'PSG', 'Olympique Lyonnais', '21:05', 'SPAL', 'Sassuolo', '@', 'Genoa', 'Cagliari', '20:30']
```

How I can get this output?

```
list = ['PSG', 'Olympique Lyonnais', '21:05', 'Genoa', 'Cagliari', '20:30']
```

In practice given the character `@`, I'd like to remove from the list `@` and the two previous elements. Another Example is the following.

- input: `[1, 2, '@', 3, 4]`
- output : `[3, 4]`

thanks

Comment: What is the specific character?

Comment: You need to explain why some values are in the output and not others...

Comment: specific carachter is '@'

Comment: Even with that character I still dont see the correlation between the lists

Answer (score 4):

You could get the indexes to remove and filter accordingly.

```
>>> indexes = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable((i,i-1,i-2) for i in range(len(l)) if l[i]=='@'))
>>> res = [el for i,el in enumerate(l) if i not in indexes]
>>> res
['PSG', 'Olympique Lyonnais', '21:05', 'Genoa', 'Cagliari', '20:30']
```

Comment: Nice answer, I couldn't seem to find the pattern he was going for

Comment: Added another example to make OP's intentions clearer.

Comment: @abc, wow... I have no idea how you figured that out from the original question.